# Copy one particular row value to multiple row

Tags: python, dataframe

I have Following data frame

```
import pandas as pd 
data = [[1,'tom', 10],[2,'adi', 20], [3,'nick', 15], [4,'juli', 14],[4,'kaushik', 10],[5,'mondal', 20], [6,'vidanshu', 15], [6,'dimpi', 14]] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['ID','Name', 'Age']) 
df
```

Now I need to copy all the values of ID 1 to all Concurrent ID

Comment: What is concurrent ID? Will it be a new colum similar with ID column? If yes you can simply use: `df['ConcurrentID'] = df['ID']`

Comment: Please post your expected output.

Comment: the required output is the same as your original df....

Comment: import pandas as pd 
data = [[1,'tom', 10],[2,'tom', 10], [3,'tom', 10], [4,'tom', 10],[4,'tom', 10],[5,'tom', 10], [6,'tom', 10], [6,'tom', 10]] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['ID','Name', 'Age']) 
df

Comment: Above data frame is my expected output. I need to copy all the values of ID 1 to all Concurrent ID

Comment: AH okay, I think I understand... Wait i will do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it this you're looking for?:

```
df['ConcurrentID'] = df['ID']

print(df)

   ID      Name  Age  ConcurrentID
0   1       tom   10             1
1   2       adi   20             2
2   3      nick   15             3
3   4      juli   14             4
4   4   kaushik   10             4
5   5    mondal   20             5
6   6  vidanshu   15             6
7   6     dimpi   14             6
```

**See below updated answer**

```
df['concurrentID'] = df['ID'].astype(str) + "_" + df['Name'].astype(str) + "_" + df['Age'].astype(str)

print(df)

   ID Name  Age concurrentID
0   1  tom   10     1_tom_10
1   2  tom   10     2_tom_10
2   3  tom   10     3_tom_10
3   4  tom   10     4_tom_10
4   4  tom   10     4_tom_10
5   5  tom   10     5_tom_10
6   6  tom   10     6_tom_10
7   6  tom   10     6_tom_10
```

Comment: import pandas as pd 
data = [[1,'tom', 10],[2,'tom', 10], [3,'tom', 10], [4,'tom', 10],[4,'tom', 10],[5,'tom', 10], [6,'tom', 10], [6,'tom', 10]] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['ID','Name', 'Age']) 
df

Comment: the above data frame is my required output

Comment: What do you mean? you completely changed your question?

Comment: So even though I answered your question above, you removed the accepted answer, and you also changed your question? that's just rude

Comment: dear sir, I need to copy all the values of ID 1 to all Concurrent IDs

Comment: expected output is

Comment: import pandas as pd 
data = [[1,'tom', 10],[2,'tom', 10], [3,'tom', 10], [4,'tom', 10],[4,'tom', 10],[5,'tom', 10], [6,'tom', 10], [6,'tom', 10]] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['ID','Name', 'Age']) 
df

Comment: If you clearly display your current DF, and your expected output, I will help you get it. If you can't do that, I can't help you.

Comment: When I put your expected output in my python to create it, it is the same as your input you have in your question. Are you still looking to create the concurrent ID column? or something else?

Comment: Check it out now?

Comment: Or do you want only the values from ID == 1 into concurrentID?